# how to properly use flutter_reactive_ble writetocharacteristic and subscribetocharacteristic in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

right now I have a bluetooth module that will send back a respond on each message receive
so if I writetocharacteristic, I need to be able to wait before reading the completed respond from the subscription.

I tried this:

```
subScribeToCharacteristic(characteristic);
writeCharacterisiticWithoutResponse(characteristic, [1]);
readValuefromSubscribedCharacteristic();
```

but I ended up reading the value too early(before the module responded)

**edited:**

here is what I have currently, how exactly do I do this properly?

```
//this is a snippet from a dialog prompting user for password that pops up after onTap of listTile of a ble device list      
  //userData = user input password of this prompt
  //this is onPressed of that ok button for the password prompt dialog


  //creates a buffer variable
  List receiveData = [];

  onPressed: () async {
  //define characteristic
  final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(characteristicId:characteristicId,serviceId: serviceId, deviceId: id);

  //subscribe to characteristic
  await ble.subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic).listen((event) {
    //if seq of data starts with byte 5550 its a match
    if (event[0] == 5 && event[1] == 5 && event[2] == 5 && event[3] == 0) {          
      print('New incoming data, inserting data to buffer');          
      receiveData = new Uint8List.fromList(event);          
    }

    print(event);        
    print(receiveData);
  });

  //send the unlock command with password
  await writeCharacteristicWithoutResponse(charateristic,userData);

  //check receiveData - result is something wrong with data if receiveData is []
  if (receiveData == Null) {
    //data is empty, so means there isnt something yet in the buffer
    print('Something wrong with data, it might be corrupt/loss packet');
  } else {
    // the module should return 1 at array[8] if module is unlocked
    if (receiveData[8] == 1) {
      //if its 1, module is unlocked and go back to previous page
      print('unlocked!!');
      Navigator.of(context).pop(userData);
    } else {
      //if its not, module is locked and reprompt the showDialog
      print('unlocked');
      
    }
  }    


  //clear receiveData afer read from it
  globals.receiveData = [0];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usage section of the [README](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble#usage) file describes the correct procedure as follows:

```
final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(serviceId: serviceUuid, characteristicId: characteristicUuid, deviceId: foundDeviceId);
flutterReactiveBle.subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic).listen((data) {
    // code to handle incoming data
}, onError: (dynamic error) {
    // code to handle errors
});
```

**Edit:**

You should move everything regarding your received data inside the listen method:

```
//this is a snippet from a dialog prompting user for password that pops up after onTap of listTile of a ble device list      
//userData = user input password of this prompt
//this is onPressed of that ok button for the password prompt dialog


//creates a buffer variable
List receiveData = [];

onPressed: () async {
    //define characteristic
    final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(characteristicId:characteristicId,serviceId: serviceId, deviceId: id);

//subscribe to characteristic
await ble.subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic).listen((event) {
    //if seq of data starts with byte 5550 its a match
    if (event[0] == 5 && event[1] == 5 && event[2] == 5 && event[3] == 0) {          
        print('New incoming data, inserting data to buffer');          
        receiveData = new Uint8List.fromList(event);          
    }

    print(event);        
    print(receiveData);

    //check receiveData - result is something wrong with data if receiveData is []
    if (receiveData == Null) {
        //data is empty, so means there isnt something yet in the buffer
        print('Something wrong with data, it might be corrupt/loss packet');
    } else {
        // the module should return 1 at array[8] if module is unlocked
        if (receiveData[8] == 1) {
            //if its 1, module is unlocked and go back to previous page
            print('unlocked!!');
            Navigator.of(context).pop(userData);
        } else {
            //if its not, module is locked and reprompt the showDialog
            print('unlocked');
      
        }
    }    

    //clear receiveData afer read from it
    globals.receiveData = [0];    
    });

    //send the unlock command with password
    await writeCharacteristicWithoutResponse(charateristic,userData);

}
```

Comment: i tried this, but does this means that for every time i want to send a data (writeToCharacteristic), i need to subscribe, and use writeTocharacteristic inside the listen method?

Comment: It should be enough to do this once. You will receive every notification inside the listen method

Comment: let say i want to send 3 different data seperately, so i would do something like
subscribe > writedata1
subscribe > writedata2
subscribe > writedata3

something like that?

because each of the writedata, expect a different response from the module.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Assuming you are writing to the same characteristic during all write operations just handle the different kind of data inside the listen method.

Comment: so its best to do
subs{ write1 then process1, write2 then process2, write3 then process3 }?

Comment: You always have to wait for one operation to finish before sending the next one. Thats why it is best to listen for notifications and send the next write after that. Please accept my answer if it was helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: it is helpful, and i did, but it says i need 15 rep to cast a vote.

Comment: upon further investigation, this doesn't help much.
because the .listen(event) of subscribe only triggers if there is a writetocharateristic even happens, so if i put subscribe.listen({writetocharacteristic()}, the writetocharacteristic will never get executed, until i writetocharacteristic somewhere else.

Comment: The answer of @M.Kotzjan is correct. You need first to listen to the subscriptions and for only the first time you need to do a writeCharacteristic outside the listen clause to trigger the first data event to be emitted by the peripheral. Then inside the listen method you use the logic for subsequent writes. Also make sure you use (and await) `writeWithResponse`.

Comment: Hi sir remoh87, I have edited my question above with what I currently have.
do you have the time to show me which part that I use it incorrectly?

Comment: @khaagong2 You are checking the data instantly after you wrote to your characteristic, but you probably did not receive any data yet. Does your `print` inside your listen method work?

Comment: yes, in listen print has the data,  but only after the print outside of listen returns empty data (the line where it says  //data is empty, so means there isnt something yet in the buffer)

Comment: @khaagong2 the reason for this is that you are not waiting for the result in `listen`. I just edited my answer with a possible solution where I moved the checking of the result inside the listen method

Comment: so the proper way to use it is

1. subscribe with expecting the result inside the .listen
2. write outside the listen after that

that way, it will always get the response it requires.

make sense. I guess I had it backwards then.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you understand it better. Please accept the answer if you think it was helpful :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I find this discussion very helpful and informative, I have been wondering the same about how to use this library correctly too, do you mind tweaking the answer a little bit more to be able to repeat the dialog prompt if password  sent is wrong?

Comment: @vontdeux assuming that the locked state means the password was incorrect that is the place to call showDialog again. `//if its not, module is locked and reprompt the showDialog`

Comment: but I saw in the commented line (1st line), that the snippet is onPressed of "ok" button in the dialog itself.

Comment: @vontdeux The snippet is not complete and I am missing a bit of context here. If you have this exact problem feel free to open another question

Comment: posted a new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605369/flutter-how-to-conditionally-repeat-a-showdialog-inside-a-listview